Parallax free projected image on diuelectric coated glass
I'm not a physician at all, just a computer scientist, so be nice with my average brain.
I'm working on an Optical System composed of:

A IR camera
A pico projector (TI DLP2000)
and a clear glass Anti-Reflection coated in one side and dielectric coated in the other side

The idea is to project a subset of data coming from the IR camera to the glass panel (20-50cm from user eyes) to have a parallax-free AR device. What probably discribe the best my project is a mixed between an AR glasses using Weaveguide lens and an holographic sight.
So I do know two optical system close to what I want to do (parallax free optics):

Red dot
Holographic sight


What I understand from my research is that parallel beam are very important (upon part alignment, optics quality, aspheric lens ...) in term of avoiding parallax. That's why Holographic sight use a Reflective collimator (top of the second schema) to parallelize the beams before sending them to the holographic grating with the engraved pattern we went to display.
with this new information, here's what I wanted to do:

As what I display is dynamic, I cannot use Holographic grating.
So it bring us to the next object of our optical system, the EYE! And here my questions are coming:
I will have parallel beam ! but my glass panel (my screen) will be way bigger than my pupil (probably 20cm diagonal), and the beams representing the projected image will all be parallel. So I am fearing that most of the beams will not hit my retina but just hit my face, leading to me seeing just a small subset of the image i'm suppose to see.
Am I missing something ? how to have a parallax free transparent display bigger than my pupil size ?
and with my eye focusing between 1m-20m (observed subject) will the projected image be clear and sharp on my retina ?
More over, did I missed something ? Over simplified the real world ?
Thanks for your time and your help !!
